# Does an app compiled with base sdk 5.0 will work on iOS4.x?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

Does an app compiled with base sdk 5.0 will work on iOS4.x ?

I have made deployment target to 4.0. Will ARC work on iOS4.x devices. Is there a way to support both in a same app? If I am using ARC in iOS5, will **memory management** occur properly in **iOS4.x** devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC is a **compiler level** feature. So it will not be affected by SDK. Apple will support ARC on 4.0 and 5.0 However, as on date, you cannot submit an app built using a beta version of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has stated that ARC will work in iOS 4 (not sure if they mentioned a specific version or if it includes iOS 4.0).  But, I don't think you can submit ARC applications until iOS5 is out...

Comment: iOS 4.0 is the bottom limit for the support of this, from what they've stated.  I believe they need that version for some runtime support.

Answer (score 0):

If deployment target is set to 4.0, the app will support all higher versions iOS including 4.0. So the answer is YES.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question is , do we need to make additional changes in the code. Because ARC is introduced only in iOS5. So will that affect working on previous ios versions, where ARC is not available? Will compiler handle all those automatically.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308425/ios-5-best-practice-release-retain