# How do I fix a memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, instruments

After doing a long profile test, I found that in one of my ".m" file memory leak occurs in the viewdidload section. i checked and the xcode highlighted the part where i have initialized picker arrays with values. my program uses pickers for user input. and i have 3 5 different views in my program. the first is a disclaimer ,the second is a menu where the user can choose the type of calculation he/she wants to do. each calculation requires certain inputs which the user enters from a picker. for eg. one of the view has 5 inputs which are handled by 5 different uipickers with seperate arrays for holding the values. these arrays are initialized with the values in the viewdidload method of that view. here is what i found after running the test:

[image: -viewDidLoad] 
...................................................................................................

[image: instantiation]

This is my first time developing an app and i'm kinda confused about what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects in objective c have a retain count. If this retain count is greater that 0 when the object goes out of scope (when you stop using it), it leaks.

The following things increase the retain count

- [[alloc] init]
- new
- copy
- [retain]
- adding an object to an array
- adding an object as a child (e.g. views)
- There are likely more, but you don't appear to use any others in your code

The following decrease the retain count

- [release]
- removing an object from an array
- if you dealloc an array, all of its objects are released

You should go through your code and ensure each of the retains or additions to an array are matched with a corresponding release. (You can release member variables in the dealloc method).

EDIT: Jeremy made a valid point that my answer doesn't

> Once you add an object to an array, it takes ownership and will release the object when it is done with it. All you need to do is make sure you release anything you own according to the memory management rules

There are also autorelease objects, have a look at this example;

```
-(init){
    ...
    stagePickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //this string is autoreleased, you don't have call release on it.
        //methods with the format [CLASS CLASSwithsomething] tend to be autorelease
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i);
        [stagePickerArray addObject:s];
    }
    ...
 }
```

I think the only thing you are missing is a call to release in your dealloc method

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    [stagepickerarray release];  //Do this for each of your arrays
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is misleading.  You do not need to match an addition to an array with a release.  Once you add an object to an array, it takes ownership and will release the object when it is done with it.  All you need to do is make sure you **release anything you own** according to the memory management rules.

Comment: Edited with a quote from your comment to clarify

Comment: Thank you so much :) . I went back and made sure all the objects I retained where released properly, such as textfields, pickers,toolbars etc etc.I also added a release for each of the arrays and after that I ran the test again. This time no memory leaks.However I have one question, during the test I also checked the allocations and the overall bytes were 9.3mb and the live bytes were 1.7 mb is that normal ? or should I be worried ?

Comment: FWIW, one could say that autoreleased objects are "owned" by the nearest autorelease pool, which will eventually release the object (when the pool is "drained"). Release is not the same as dealloc/free, so if there are other references to the object, it will not be dealloc-ed yet. Only if the last reference is released, i.e. the retain count reaches 0, the object will be "freed" (dealloc-ed).

Comment: Also, I tend to use the class convenience methods (those that start with the class name, like `stringWithFormat:`, `arrayWithObjects:` or `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:`, etc.) a lot for **temporary** objects. These usually return autoreleased objects, so I don't have to worry about releasing them when the pointer that points to them leaves scope.

Answer (score 2):

The leaks tool will only tell you where yo allocated the objects that it thinks leaks.  So, it's telling you, for instance, that

```
NSString* answer = [NSString stringWithFormat: ...
```

allocates an object that is never deallocated.  Now, `-stringWithFormat:` gives you an object that [you do not own](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) and you don't seem to retain it anywhere.  Therefore, you do not need to release it, so it can't be leaking by itself.

That means something else that you *do* own must be retaining it and you never release that something else.  The prime suspect would appear to be `stagePickerArray`.  Check that you are releasing `stagePickerArray` somewhere.  If it's local to `-viewDidLoad` it must be released or autoreleased before the end of that method.  If it's an instance variable, it must be released in the class's `-dealloc` method.

Comment: Thank you :) I forgot to add the release for the array ! and that was the cause of the problem !

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C you need to take care of the retain count of allocated memory. If you don't need it -> release it.

Whenever you alloc an object, it will return an object with retain count = 1.

By using retain, the retain count gets incremented,
by using release, the retain count gets decremented.
Whenever the retain count is equals 0, the object will be destroyed.

So whenever you want to use the object somewhere else you need to retain it. So you make sure that the object is not deleted after the other 'person' (or whatever it used ;)) called release.

This was a very very very short description. Check the following guide 
[Memory Management Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).

(Also you want to read something about ARC - Automatic Retain Counting - which is new in iOS5! [ios5 best practice release retain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308425/ios-5-best-practice-release-retain)

Comment: Thank you :). I'll have a look into that ! . I'm currently using iOS 4 xD