# I seem to be getting a huge amount of errors in XCode with ASI HTTP Request?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

I am getting about thirty issues already with the files which I downloaded from http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/.

See http://f.cl.ly/items/0J0l3w1t1n222N3E3v44/ASIErrors.tiff for a few errors highlighted in XCode.

Do I have to go through each one individually to fix or is there a simple fix?

**EDIT: It seems to be something to do with "ARC"?**

Thanks!

Comment: You need to just turn off ARC on those files. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308425/ios-5-best-practice-release-retain/6429909#6429909) is a link that can help you on how to do that.

Comment: It should possibly be noted that the original maintainer of ASIHTTPRequest has stopped maintaining it (`http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release];`) and suggest people start looking for other libraries. For example [AFNetworking](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking), he also points to a few other ones (see his post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you're trying to compile with XCode 4.2 / iOS 5. You'll need to turn off ARC. Here's an article that shows how to do it for the whole project:

http://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/disabling-the-arc-in-xcode-4-2/