# Reachability error checking for network type on ios

Tags: iphone, ios, reachability

I am trying to detect network connectivity using apples sample reachability code as well as this code below.

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(status == NotReachable) 
    {
        //No internet
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        //WiFi
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
    {
        //3G
    }

    [reachability stopNotifier];
}
```

I have also added systemConfiguration. framework to my project and added **-fno-objc-arc** to the compiler source for the reachibility file to be compatible with ARC, how ever I am currently getting this error...

```
 "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
          +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in Reachability.o
      "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
          +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in Reachability.o
      "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
          -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o
      "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
          -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
      "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
          -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
      "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
          -[Reachability connectionRequired] in Reachability.o
          -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in Reachability.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Reachability version for ARC in iOS5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797008/need-reachability-version-for-arc-in-ios5)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Reachability.m is in your Compile Sources list under Build Phases and run again.  Also make sure the Reachability class isn't #importing itself, and that it is #importing its header file.   I would also check that your Reachability class is actually #importing the SystemConfiguration framework, as all of your errors are based on methods found in it.

Comment: okay its in Build Phases, and also have Imported SystemConfiguration.framework.. however not quite sure what you are referring to wit h" make sure the Reachability class isn't #importing itself, and that it is #importing its header file"

Comment: In Reachability .m, does it `#import reachability.h` or .m?

Comment: yea I just checked and it dose #import the .h file from the .m file.. removing it however generates more errors.