# Does Reachability need to be included when using Twitter/FB sharing sheets?

Tags: ios, reachability

Does Apple's Reachability class need to be included in an app that allows sharing via the built-in Facebook and Twitter sharing sheets? That's the only area of my app that would require any kind of network call, but since it's a system level function and my app isn't directly talking to Twitter/Facebook, I thought I might not need to include it.

On a related note, if my app sends a user to Safari for a help page, do I need to include Reachability for that? My app wouldn't be making any network calls there, either.

Comment: ewiinnnn is correct here: you're not obliged to use Reachability in any case - you can "simply" handle connection errors afterwards. But it sure is more user frinedly to modify your UI at the moment the user looses internet connection and not only after a certain request fails.

Comment: I thought Reachability was required for any App Store app that connects to the Internet?

Comment: Nope (at least i believe so), but it is kind of a good practice. I think Apple's version of Reachability is not even directly ARC compatible. This one works nice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8137506/653513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, reachability is used to check the availabilty of internet connection. This is usually useful if you want to make sure that the device currently have internet connection before attempting any network-related operation. However, this is not obligatory.