# Error Message: ARC is required to compile Pushwoosh SDK

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, pushwoosh

I am new in xcode.
I got recurring message error when building for testing:

```
*PWRequest.m
User defined issues
"ARC is required to compile Pushwoosh SDK"*
```

In code it shows:
    #if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
    #error "ARC is required to compile Pushwoosh SDK"
    #endif

I don't understand. I added a new pushwoosh sdk.
I thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can set ARC on a file basis. Go to the BuildPhases->CompileSources. You can select sources there and pass ARC flag.
   Same as here:
   [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)
   but with -fobjc-arc  flag
2. You can use XCode project that comes with the SDK. In this case you'll be linking to the output (library) that is produced by this project.

Hope it helps!

Comment: now pushwhoosh become framework...how to disable arc for pre-built in framework ?

Comment: There is no such thing as arc for framework. Arc works on a source code level, framework is a compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use Pushwoosh in your app, you're going to need to turn on ARC in your project settings.

And then you'll be using ARC in your app.

Which is somewhat nicer than doing good old fashioned Manual Retain / Release memory management, yes?

If you are determined to use MRC (manual retain count), [then follow the steps in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967415/could-i-build-a-arc-framework-and-use-it-in-a-non-arc-project).