# How to include non ARC farmework in ARC enabled project in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, automatic-ref-counting

I am facing one issue while I am adding personal non ARC framework in my ARC project. Many errors are there like ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs. For this I dont want to opt for this solution: "__unsafe_unretained". I want to know from you all expert people that is there any way so that I can add my non arc framework in ARC enabled project?

Comment: disbale ARC for non ARC framework.

Comment: do you have the framework code?

Comment: mayank: How to do that?
Rajesh: Yes I have framework code

Comment: Try with this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967415/could-i-build-a-arc-framework-and-use-it-in-a-non-arc-project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to add compiler flags in `Xcode ->Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources`.
Just double click on the column of the row under **compiler flag**, here you can select multiple file by using **cmd** and then can disable the **ARC** for framework, u need to add the `-fno-objc-arc` in every perticular file.

[image: see image]
 Now clean and build the project and run, it'll work fine..

Comment: to set this flag for many files select all (with shift or command) and press enter to open options popover.

Comment: you can select by only command using mouse

Comment: I dont want to do this. This is file specific approach. How to do this for framework? I have one framework e.g "stack.framework" and I have added that in my project. That framework is non arc and my project is arc. Now tell me how to do this step. Frameworks .m files will not come to my project.

Answer (score 0):

go to your project's target-> build phases->compile sources->file you want to disbale ARC-> double click on file and write -fno-objc-arc
[image]

Comment: I dont want to do this. This is file specific approach. How to do this for framework? I have one framework e.g "stack.framework" and I have added that in my project. That framework is non arc and my project is arc. Now tell me how to do this step. Frameworks .m files will not come to my project.