# Developing Iphone app for iOS 4.0 in iOS 5.0?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I developing iPhone application for iOS 4.2 using latest SDK iOS5. I trying to add external classes [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal/tree/)

but i gives me error "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease', 'retain', and 'release'". And i want to add this classes in my application in any how condition.
I want to execute that classes in my application.
I stuck on two points basically,
1) How i use explicit use of retain, release, and autorelease keywords
2) How i deploy my app on 4.0 lower version from latest iOS 5.0(Containing ARC scheme)

Thanks
RRB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a refactoring that will convert your classes to be compatible with ARC.

In XCode menu: Edit - Refactor - Convert to Objective-C ARC.

Comment: suppose i refactoring all classes in ARC environment then it will execute already written retain, release keywords? Also suppose it will Ran in ARC environment then it will run in lower version of iOS 5?

Comment: @RRB: refactoring will remove all retain and release keywords because they are not needed anymore, ARC code will run on iOS 4.x and later.

Comment: Thanks dude it working for me on simulator only let me check on device.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) for an explanation of how to disable ARC on a per-file basis. The solution here is probably to disable ARC for the Kal files while leaving it enabled for the rest of your project. (ARC works fine on iOS 4.0 with a couple of minor exceptions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the ARC off in the Xcode 4.2 for your project.

For more info , see [the blogpost](http://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/disabling-the-arc-in-xcode-4-2/)

Also , see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308425/ios-5-best-practice-release-retain)