# AutoRelease interfering with data handling

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, autorelease

So I'm working from [This Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) and trying to build an XML reader into my application with a self-built api. I'm attempting to read through an xml, and keep getting this error:

```
*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x68675a0
```

I'm not releasing or deallocating anything, I'm letting the AutoRelease handle all of that. Here is my call for the method:

```
self.dtContact = [DTContactParser loadDTC];   

if (_dtContact != nil) {
    for (DTContact *dtc in _dtContact.contacts) {
        NSLog(@"%@", dtc.description);
}
}
NSLog(@"done");
```

I get my error at the end of this, when it sends the `NSLog(@"done");`, then it throws the error.

Here is the DTContactParser's loadDTC

```
+ (DTCXMLResponse *)loadDTC {

NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath:FALSE];
NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error;
GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData 
                                                       options:0 error:&error];
if (doc == nil) { return nil; }

DTCXMLResponse *dtcxmlr = [[DTCXMLResponse alloc] init];
NSArray *dtcontacts = [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"DetectiveContact"];
for (GDataXMLElement *dtcontact in dtcontacts) {

    // Let's fill these in!
    NSString *description;
    int dtcid;

    // Name
    NSArray *descriptions = [dtcontact elementsForName:@"description"];
    if (descriptions.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *firstName = (GDataXMLElement *) [descriptions objectAtIndex:0];
        description = firstName.stringValue;
    } else continue;

    // Level
    NSArray *ids = [dtcontact elementsForName:@"idDetectiveContact"];
    if (ids.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *firstID = (GDataXMLElement *) [ids objectAtIndex:0];
        dtcid = firstID.stringValue.intValue;
    } else continue;

    DTContact *dtcontact = [[DTContact alloc] initWithName:description dtId:dtcid];
    [dtcxmlr.contacts addObject:dtcontact];


return nil;
```

}
}

And here is the DTContact:

```
    #import "DTContact.h"

@implementation DTContact
@synthesize description = _description;
@synthesize dtId = _dtId;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)description dtId:(int)dtId{

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.description = description;
        self.dtId = dtId;
    }    
    return self;

}
```

@end

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using this answer to a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308425/ios-5-best-practice-release-retain/6429909#6429909), I have disabled ARC on my GDATAXML library and it stops causing the error.