# Is there a way to keep entire projects WITHOUT ARC whilst using ARC on new projects

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have been refraining from upgrading Xcode until one specific project is out of the way, which is coming soon. I would like to be able to use ARC for future projects while keeping the ability to maintain and investigate issues with prior software products.

Question is can this be done with a single install of Xcode ? When I upgrade Xcode, will I be able to exclude ARC completely from some projects, and continue working without changing **anything** in those projects?

Comment: do you mean this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308425/ios-5-best-practice-release-retain

Comment: @hib : no, i meant THIS question. Notice the emphasis on 'anything' ... i would rather open and start debugging a prior project without having to worry about any changes that could be introduced by the brand spankin new Xcode unbeknownst to me at project open time. If it is not possible, I will deal with it, but non-regression testing is expensive in time and resources.

Comment: oh sorry . you got the answer after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. ARC is a build option for each project, or can even be enabled/disabled per-file.

Comment: so, when I open one of these antiques :) , the xcodeproj file will be read and understood properly, without any intrusive changes to it to enable ARC ? ie if it compiled and ran before, it will still do that with the freshly updated Xcode.

Comment: Nope, they should still work fine. Depending on the version of Xcode, you might be compiling against a different SDK, so they may be issues with that, but ARC won't present any problem.

Comment: Well, if my use of SDK is probably totally backward compatible in those projects, that would be a lesser concern for me. Will be upgrading from Xcode 4.1.1 targeting iOS 4, to the newest out there. Thanks.

Comment: where is the ARC settings for an individual project?

Comment: actually i just noticed it is a global setting when you create a new project, and it is turned off by default. that makes it easy.

Comment: @andrewx - hehehe ... that should make it easier then. I will still make a full 'other git' repo and 2 copies of each project beforehand, but it is reassuring to know. Thanks.

Comment: wow, that went like a charm , i guess it must be my third update on Xcode :). This is the first one that did not turn out to be a walk through hell for me.