# Errors on JSONKit implement

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jsonkit

[image: The Errors]

Upon importing the **JSONKit.h** and  **JSONKit.m** files into my project , i get the following errors. I have browsed and browsed but none seems to have encountered these problems ?

All i did was import the files and build and then i get this

Is it something i forgot to import or ...??????

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can disable ARC(automatic reference count) in JSONKit files.

Generally step is :

1. Go to your project settings, under Build Phases > Compile Sources
2. Select the files you want ARC disabled and add -fno-objc-arc compiler flags. You can set flags for multiple files in one shot by selecting the files then hitting "Enter" key.

Please refer to this post: [iOS 5 Best Practice (Release/retain?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308425/ios-5-best-practice-release-retain) for more details.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

After discussion, we also have some other options to solve the problem. For example, you can convert JSONKit to ARC compatible. But according to `Mike Weller`'s statement, it will be very hard to convert because JSONKit uses `malloc` to manage memory.

I think use `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag is a low-risk and convenient way to solve the problem.

Comment: @ParthBhatt Yes, I agree. There must be some other methods can solve this problem. For example, we can change the JSONKit to some other json lib which supports GCD. Using -fno-objc-arc compiler flags is a low-risk way to solve this problem in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

tangqiaoboy's answer will resolve those errors but you can also consider using the class NSJSONSerialization. It makes it really easy do convert NSDictionarys and NSArrays to JSON and vice-versa.

Good luck!

Comment: As far as I know, `NSJSONSerialization` only exist in ios5. If we want to support ios4, we have to use 3rd part lib.

Answer (score -2):

You can convert your project into `ARC` compatible, by following steps

Go to `Edit menu -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC...`

Or If you `do not` want to use `ARC` in your current project then follow `tangqiaoboy` 's steps.

Comment: JSONKit does not work with ARC because of it's custom memory management.

Comment: @MikeWeller : I am currently using JSONKit with ARC without any problem ?? I dont think you have ever tried JSONKit with ARC !!

Comment: Because JSONKit explicitly does not support it. It uses malloc and free internally to allocate object memory. ARC does not work with custom object allocation.

Comment: @Devang You can use JSONKit in an ARC project. You cannot compile or convert JSONKit as ARC-enabled code, as this answer was suggesting. You need to change the compiler settings for the JSONKit files.

Comment: @MikeWeller  You can replace those with `_bridged` and `strong` keywords to work on custom allocations. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: JSONKit allocates the memory for objective-c objects using malloc. Under ARC, you *must* allocate objects using `alloc`. Otherwise ARC will attempt to deallocate JSONKit objects assuming they have been allocated by the system. This will not work.

Comment: I think after effort, JSONKit can be converted to ARC compatible.But It will have update problem when JSONKit has new patch. Using -fno-objc-arc compiler flags is a low-risk way to solve this problem.