# ARC refactored Facebook Hackbook for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having difficulty refactoring the Facebook Hackbook for iOS sample code. Does anyone know of any sample code where this has already been done?

thanks for any help.

Comment: Would you like to compile Facebook API under ARC Mode? Try to turn off ARC mode for these API with the flag "-fno-objc-arc". see "sudo rm -rf" answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308425/ios-5-best-practice-release-retain